# chmod 0644 :Operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, chmod

i wanted to download java using sudo apt on ubuntu 18.04 but it sent me "E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?"

so i tried to run "apt-get update" which sent me lots of error that looks like this " chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_InRelease failed - 201::URIDone (1: Operation not permitted)" so i tried to change the permission using  chmod 0644 /var/lib/apt/lists/"
but it didn't work also tried a couple other methods but still didn't work

so hopefully you can tell me what to try to fix it.
btw i'm using windows 10 and running ubuntu 18.04 from the windows store

Comment: do you run apt-get as super user? (using `sudo`)

Comment: yes i ran it as a super user

Comment: try to remove those files `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and rerun `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: it returned
""rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial': Is a directory""

Comment: try use `rm -r`

Comment: yep it worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove those files `sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and rerun `sudo apt-get update`